# Batch: Create a Folder and Name it by Today's Date

Tags: date, batch-file, calendar, directory

How can I make a batch file that will create a folder (in a specified directory) that will create a folder and label it with today's date? Can I also make it delete folders that are one week old or older?

Answer (score 3):

One question at a time. Addressing your first one:

```
cd \YourSpecificDirectory
SET Today=%Date:~10,4%%Date:~4,2%%Date:~7,2%
REN Creates folder in format 20050812  (depending on regional settings and language)
md %Today%
```

Answers to your second question (how to delete a folder before a certain date) already exist here. A search should find them for you pretty easily.

Comment: +1 Clarified that the folder format with the code above is not fixed, as the %date% variable changes with region and language and user preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this post how to get data value independent of data/Time format (zone):
[batch file to copy some files and changing their name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078628/batch-file-to-copy-some-files-and-changing-their-name)